# Is there a name for a concatenation-exponentiation relation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Suppose we define a set:
$$
S := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}  | x^y =y \mathbin\Vert x\} 
$$
where "$\mathbin\Vert$" denotes the concatenation operation.

We have the example of the pair of number $(5,2) \in S$.
This is because $5^2 = 25 = 2 \mathbin\Vert 5$.

My question is, does there exist a name for these types of numbers or a similar definition (say the numbers belong in a more general set than $ \mathbb{N}$, for example)? And if so, is there any documented research done with similar types of numbers?

Comment: What is $\pi \| e$?

Comment: I made a mistake writing the problem, thank you for pointing it out.
Edited the problem to fix that!

Comment: I don't see a difference between $S$ and the set of ordered pairs of natural numbers. Also, your question is not clear. Why have you introduced a new notation for exponentiation? What are your questions, more clearly? For otherwise, there is a name of course -- these are just the natural numbers under exponentiation.

Comment: What I was trying to write was the set of integers in which $a^b$ happens to also be the number $a \mathbin\Vert b$. What would be the correct way to write this set?

Comment: Other examples?  How many are in S?

Comment: Are you assuming base 10, decimal, for the concatenation operation? The reliance on a base is one reason why such problems are usually considered toy problems, not worthy of research. Do I doubt you'll find any "documented research" on such numbers.

Comment: $S$ is finite. In fact, it is very small. You can doubtlessly find all examples with very little searching, and I suspect you've listed the only example with both $x, y > 1$. The reason is that $x^y$ grows much faster with $x$ and $y$ than $y\|x$ does.